# Return multiple input (Python)

Tags: input, python-3.x

In python 3 I have a line asking for input that will then look in an imported dictionary and then list all their inputs that appear in the dictionary. My problem is when I run the code and put in the input it will only return the last word I input.
For example
the dictionary contains (AIR, AMA)
and if I input (AIR, AMA) it will only return AMA.
Any information to resolve this would be very helpful!

The dictionary:

```
EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
                 ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
                 ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22),
```

The Code:

```
import shares
a=input("Please input")
s1 = a.replace(' ' , "")
print ('Please list portfolio: ' + a)
print (" ")
n=["Code", "Name", "Price"]
print ('{0: <6}'.format(n[0]) + '{0:<20}'.format(n[1]) + '{0:>8}'.format(n[2]))
z = shares.EXCHANGE_DATA[0:][0]
b=s1.upper()
c=b.split()
f=shares.EXCHANGE_DATA
def find(f, a):
    return [s for s in f if a.upper() in s]
x= (find(f, str(a)))
toDisplay = []
a = a.split()
for i in a:
    temp = find(f, i)
    if(temp):
        toDisplay.append(temp)
for i in toDisplay:
    print ('{0: <6}'.format(i[0][0]) + '{0:<20}'.format(i[0][1]) + ("{0:>8.2f}".format(i[0][2])))
```

Comment: A code sample would help, as I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Updated with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the code seems somewhat confused. Here's a simpler version that seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
                 ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
                 ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22)]

user_input = input("Please Specify Shares: ")

names = set(user_input.upper().split())

print ('Listing the following shares: ' + str(names))
print (" ")

# Print header
n=["Code", "Name", "Price"]
print ('{0: <6}{1:<20}{2:>8}'.format(n[0],n[1],n[2]))

#print data
for i in [data for data in EXCHANGE_DATA if data[0] in names]:
  print ('{0: <6}{1:<20}{2:>8}'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

And here's an example of use:

```
➤ python3 program.py 
Please Specify Shares: air amp
Listing the following shares: {'AMP', 'AIR'}

Code  Name                   Price
AIR   Airnz                    5.6
AMP   Amp                     3.22
```

The code sample you provided actually does what was expected, if you gave it space separated quote names.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! this certainly makes it clearer, is it at all possible for it to work in the same way if the input contained commas? (for example air, amp, aia) thanks again

Comment: you can do that by using the `re` module to split the input. for example, replace `names = set(user_input.upper().split())` by `names = set(re.split("[\t., ]*", user_input))` have a look at the [documentation for the re module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to learn more.

Comment: Also note that the solution above is computationally expensive (goes through the list of every share price) and there might be better ways of doing it.